# Program to do something like this?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm sorry if the question is too obvious but how can I do a image like this in a more or less easy way?

https://www.instagram.com/p/Bx91a3oCXUB/

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xwwzoe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use ***any*** application capable of changing the color of text - there are probably hundreds, if not thousands - from Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign to Scribus, Sketch, Affinity, to Word, MSPaint, Paintshop Pro, Gimp, Inkscape...
- Type a paragraph
- Select the entire paragraph, set its color to the lighter color you wish to use
- Select a section of the paragraph, set the color to black

Comment: You forgot to mention that the web browser can do this. So in fact the application OP typed this question into could have done it

Answer (score 0):

One way i see this happening, is on Photoshop or After Effects, you get a white background layer, or an image that suits your needs, select the font and type the text. Then mark the text you want slightly faded out and reduce its opacity (or type it into seperate layers and manipulate those) until you're satisfied with the result. Hope this helps.